# Why one tfs build summary shows test results on one machine, not on another

Tags: testing, tfs, tfsbuild, mstest, summary

I have a TFS build and some unit tests. Build runs, test runs on build server. 
But: On one machine, I can see test results, not on another. See screenshots. (Ignore the failed tests, there is no test results that's the matter)

The same is on the web-UI: with one user account I can see "test Results" and stats, on another machine (with another user account) there is a message "Test result with ID 123 not found or deleted".

I even don't know where the Test Result file might be located. Is there a permission problem?

[image: different content, same build summary]

Comment: Do you really see a difference with the same user on the two machines, or is it only for one of the users on any machine? What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Maybe the test results were just not ready yet?

Comment: Do you use the same VS edition on two machines?

Comment: On server side TFS2015 is running. I have these differences in Visual Studio as well as in the Web-UI. Tests are completed. A colleague of mine can see the results one other not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test results are stored in the collection database so given that the two users have the same rights on the team project they should be able to see the same build details.

You could investigate if the two users have appointed different Access level (license level) through the admin pages: http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses. I am not completely sure if a Stakeholder is allowed to see test results from builds.

Comment: At least developers should read the test results. I have an 'admin' role and my colleague as well, so that's might be a valuable hint

Comment: Even if I add user directly to the role 'stakeholder' or 'advanced' they can not see Testresults.

Comment: On "Group" => security => I set  "View test runs" to 'Allow'. Now it works.